# How to transition when html added using js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to transition this h1 when we click on the button, the html for the `h1` is added using js, so it is dynamic, I can't specify the opacity 0 and other before the button click, what is the way to do this?

```js
const wow = document.getElementById('wow');
const test = document.querySelector('.test');

wow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    test.innerHTML = `
  <h1 class="title">
        Hello Test
    </h1>
  `;
})
```

```css
.title {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) .1s,opacity 1s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>

<button id="wow">
  Click
</button>
```

Comment: you'll want to maybe add a class after adding the innerHTML, and do your transition that way

Comment: Covered by "[How can I get CSS transitions to run on a newly created HTML element by adding a class?](/q/41937640/90527)", though this question is a few steps before.

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to the parent, then create CSS which reveals the child when the parent has the class you created ... e.g. `reveal` in this case

The setTimeout is needed so that the initial content is added to the DOM pre-transitioned, so that it transitions

```js
const wow = document.getElementById('wow');
const test = document.querySelector('.test');

wow.addEventListener('click', () => {
  test.innerHTML = `<h1 class="title">Hello Test</h1>`;
  setTimeout(() => test.classList.add('reveal'), 0);
})
```

```css
.title {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100vh);
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1) .1s, opacity 1s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1) .2s;
}

.reveal .title {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>

<button id="wow">
  Click
</button>
```

---

I was going to use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout` ... but, oddly, that didn't work (has me a little perplexed) ... had to do

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame() => test.classList.add('reveal')));
```

I know why that definitely works, I just don't understand why a single RAF doesn't - at least in firefox, probably works fine in those other browsers)

maybe `setTimeout` always triggers after at least one render cycle, but requestAnimationFrame does not?

Comment: But as you can see, it initially taken up the space even it is not there, and after that it transform according to the class, I want to do transition once it is clicked button

Comment: `it initially taken up the space even it is not there` no it doesn't - did you want it to?

Comment: RE: 2 RAF calls: MDN's page for [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) states: "[it] will request that your animation function be called before the browser performs the next repaint." (Other parts of the page say something similar.) A single call will complete before the next repaint, which is likely the same frame that the newly created element is displayed. The double-call ensures there's at least one repaint in between, so changes resulting from the new class will be displayed starting with the 2nd frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this element in HTML first, but set its opacity to 0, and then animate it by switching CLASS

**titleNotShow** ==> **show**

```html
<div class="test">
  <h1 class="titleNotShow">
    Hello Test
  </h1>
   </div>

<button id="wow">
  Click
</button>
```

```js
const wow = document.getElementById('wow');
const test = document.querySelector('.test');

wow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    test.className = 'show'
})
```

```css
.titleNotShow {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.show{
opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) .1s,opacity 1s cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1) .2s;
}
```

Comment: none of your snippets do anything

Comment: I don't want to define it before

Comment: @Bravo that's probably because this should all be _one_ snippet, and not three separate ones.

Comment: Allright he don't want to define it before

Comment: @CBroe - probably because it doesn't actually work :D oh, and, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

After adding the `innerHTML`, you can use `setTimeout` to transform the h1, after a delay of 1 millisecond. You can select the element using `querySelector`.

```js
const wow = document.getElementById('wow');
const test = document.querySelector('.test');

wow.addEventListener('click', () => {
  test.innerHTML = `<h1 class="title">Hello Test</h1>`;
  setTimeout(() => test.querySelector(".title").style.transform = "translateY(100px)", 1)
})
```

```css
.title {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1) .1s, opacity 1s cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1) .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>

<button id="wow">
  Click
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into jQuery's fadeTo() or animate() functions
https://api.jquery.com/fadein/, https://api.jquery.com/animate/

In the example I've put a 1000 duration, you may want to reduce it. You may also want to hide the button, or use the toggle() function to alternate between hide/show https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```js
$( "#wow" ).click(function() {
  $( ".test" ).animate({
    opacity: 1,
    height: 'show',
    marginTop: 'show',
    marginBottom: 'show',
    paddingTop: 'show',
    paddingBottom: 'show'
  },  
  1000)
});
```

```css
.test { opacity: 0; display:none}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="test">Hello test!</h1>

<button id="wow">
  Click
</button>
```